# error: request for member 'next' in something not a structure or union.What does that mean?

Tags: c, linked-list

I've been training with linked lists and I have written the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node *ptr;
struct node
{
    int element;
    ptr next;
};
typedef ptr list;
typedef ptr position;

int main()
{
    struct node nod1;
    struct node nod2;
    struct node nod3;

    nod1.element=87;
    nod2.element=87;
    nod3.element=98;

    nod1.next=&nod2;
    nod2.next=&nod3;
    nod3.next=NULL;

    list L;
    L.next=&nod1;

    printlist(L);

    return 0;
}

void printlist(list l)
{
    position p;
    p=(l)-> next;
    while(p!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d",(p)-> element);
        p=p->next;
    }
}
```

The error I got is in this statement :

```
L.next=&nod1;
```

I can't understand why because I have already defined "`list`" in the beginning of the code, and the type "`ptr`" is already defined too:

```
typedef ptr list;
```

Comment: Please indent your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the definition, you have to change

```
L.next=&nod1;
```

to

```
L->next=&nod1;
```

because in your code, `L` is of type `struct node *`.

To avoid confusion, do not `typedef` pointers. At times, they become very tricky to handle.

Next, as pointed out by Mr. **@ WhozCraig** in below comment, once you have solved this issue, you **have** to allocate memory to `L` (or any pointer, for that matter) before using it. Otherwise, using uninitalized pointer invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Note to OP. Once this is fixed your code will compile, but will invoke *undefined behavior*. `L` is never set to a determinate non-null address.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks for the comment will add that info to anser itself, with your permission. :-)

Comment: It is your answer, man, add whatever you think appropriate. No worries from me.

Comment: @WhozCraig nothing's really yours or mine sir, after all, it's a collaborative effort, isn't it? :-)

Comment: @WhozCraig and Sourav Ghosh Thanks for your help . I got it well now :)

Answer (score 2):

You defined a new type `ptr` which is of type `struct node *` (pointer to `struct node` type). After that you defined `list` as a `ptr` type. Therefore

```
list L;
```

will declare `L` as a *pointer to `struct node`*. Since `L` is a pointer to structure, you need a `->` operator to access the elements it points to. First allocate the memory for `L`

```
L = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

and then

```
L->next=&nod1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it like

```
L->next = (struct node *) &nod1;
```

Comment: `L->next` and `&node1` are of same type. No need of cast.